# Typo3 11.5 and 10.4 install via Composer and from zip fails, is this possible to use Typo3 anymore?

Tags: composer-php, typo3

I tried to install `Typo 3 11.5` from `zip` and Composer and the result was `404` to Backend.
In log files, there is no information. I tried some topics with config in files but I don't have these config files.

Next, I tried to install `10.4` via composer and it failed:

> Script typo3cms install:fixfolderstructure handling the
> typo3-cms-scripts event returned with error code 255 Script
> @typo3-cms-scripts was called via post-autoload-dump

in:

> \public\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Database\Driver\PDOStatement.php on
> line 67

I followed the Installation Guide from the website every time.

I am not sure you can help me with this pure "error log" above but:

**Does someone install `Typo3` successfully last time, could you provide some information how you did it?**

P.S. Every .zip pckage has `public` folder missing and it doesn't create after installation complete.
But the installation guide require `public` folder:

```
cd public
mklink /d typo3_src ..\typo3_src-10.4.x
mklink /d typo3 typo3_src\typo3
mklink index.php typo3_src\index.php
```

I cannot do this step. Source:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/10.4/en-us/QuickInstall/GetAndUnpack/Index.html

Comment: I think there is something mixed up. The zip-packages are production ready, and do not need any composer commands anymore. That's the classic installation. The is no need for a public-folder in the zip, as you only use the typo3_src-10.4.x\typo3 folder and the typo3_src-10.4.x\index.php  (both via symlink)
If you install via composer, you need a root composer.json that requires the TYPO3 sources.

Comment: Regarding the public-folder for non-composer installations: That's simply your document root of your hosting environment. It should be there. It is simply named differently everywhere. Can be `html` or `htdocs` or `public` ...

Comment: @MKlein Thanks.
I don't know why zip instalations didn't work, it was my guess about public folder.
Always after installation and check "Go to backend" option I get 404.

I can't install 11.5 via composer due to error above. I am lack of ideas what to do. I supposed I will copy everything from zip file to my Ftp and use it like Wordpress or Joomla. Both CMS are working well on my hosting but not Typo3.

Comment: The zip-version should work like wordpress and others. The 404 error simply means you obviously put something into the wrong folder. Assuming your document-root folder is named "public" and you have direct access via FTP, simply upload the typo3_src-10.4.28 folder there and create the 2 symlinks:
ln -snf typo3_src-10.4.28/typo3; ln -snf typo3_src-10.4.28/index.php; touch FIRST_INSTALL
Point the browser to your domain and the installer should come up.

Comment: @MKlein I putted it in root folder like guide tells. 
Installer works, like I have written the problems shows after installation when I want to go to backend.
I have installed 10.4 sucessfully but after installation I cicked "reate blanc page" or comething.

Comment: Of course I am not sure it it helped but I didnt do anything more. I uploaded everything like before.

Answer (score 0):

Is mod rewrite activated for your hosting environment?

Starting with TYPO3 11 the backend uses proper routing which also needs mod_rewrite (or similar configuration for nginx) in the Backend.